# Select the corresponding list depending on the language

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a method where I need to detect the language first and then depending on the language iterate over the corresponding list of values (translated into this language). 
My initial idea is to create lists of values for the required set of languages and then use a dictionary to do the mapping.

```
words_en = [] # English values here
words_de = [] # German values here
words_fr = [] # French values here
current_language = detect_language(img_txt) # possible_values: en, de, fr
lang_mapping = {'en':words_en, 'de': words_de, 'fr': words_fr} 
lang_list = lang_mapping[current_language]
```

This case looks okay, but in practice I might have to deal with many more languages which requires creating plenty of lists in the same manner as above. Probably, there is a more idiomatic/concise solution? Thank you!

Comment: For me, this approach seems legit. The question is, how to fill those lists with words, e.g., `words_en`? Creating those lists for many differnt languages manually seems a lot of effort. But the information you provide is not enough to help you with this concern.

Comment: I think this is a case for NLP, try reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to define lists of values out of the dictionary, you can put them inside and avoid setting extra names for them:

```
current_language = detect_language(img_txt) # possible_values: en, de, fr
lang_mapping = {'en': [], 'de': [], 'fr': []}
lang_list = lang_mapping[current_language]
```

Comment: I suppose the dict might get unnecessarily lengthy if I keep all those lists inside.

Comment: The length of the dict remains 3 (the number of the keys) and each value is actually a pointer to a list (either it is defined outside or inside the dict). I don' t think it affects in dict efficiency in any way.